# Value of /proc/sys/kernel/hostname

Tags: linux, proc, hostname, etc

I've set computer hostname in `/etc/hostname` a while ago (also there are record in `/etc/hosts`). Everything worked fine, but recently I've noticed that value of `hostname` (and `/proc/sys/kernel/hostname`) changed (to hostname of neighbour computer), although I haven't touched anything related. Value of `/etc/hostname` remains correct. Which mechanism may cause such change?

There are [similar problem description](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-general-1/proc-sys-kernel-hostname-quesiton-266250/), but it doesn't contains any solution.

Comment: What Linux distribution and version are you running?

Comment: In addition.  Are there naming services running?

Comment: @Banjer Debian stable

Comment: @Karlson No, I don't use any

Answer (score 0):

It's possible your kernel has autoconfiguration enabled and the DHCP server on your network is supplying this hostname.

Usually the DHCP hostname is ignored if `/etc/hostname` is present (systemd-networkd does this, for example) but given the age of your question I would guess that whatever was handling network configuration at the time was taking the hostname from the DHCP response in preference to the one configured manually.

If you want to check this, run a program such as Wireshark and have it listen to your network traffic.  Type in a filter of `dhcp` and then unplug and replug your network cable.  You should see the DHCP responses appear and you can examine them in the Wireshark window to see what hostname the server is sending you.  If it matches the one you are seeing, that confirms where it's coming from.  The solution will then be to configure your system to ignore host names specified in DHCP response messages.